# hospot problem on andriod 6 on sony experia z3

Tags: sony-xperia-z3

I am using android 6 when I open the hotspot setting they give the error " Tattering Hotspot Creating failed". When I use pda net for creating hotspot it will easily created. What the problem behind them?

Comment: Use [tag:logcat] to find out the problem.

Comment: @Firelord explain your answer